# Passing the response of one API to another subsequent API call [Gatling]

Tags: scala, gatling

I have this script which has 3 api calls, where the response of first api call contains an "id" field which should be passed to the other two subsequent api calls.

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MySimulation extends Simulation {
  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("https://api.example.com")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")

  val organizationId = "org123"
  val locationId = "loc123"
  val serviceId = "svc123"

  val scn = scenario("My Scenario")
    .exec(http("Create Walkin")
      .post(s"/organizations/${organizationId}/locations/${locationId}/services/${serviceId}/resources/walkins")
      .body(StringBody("""{ "source": "WEB_KIOSK" }""")).asJson
      .check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("walkInId")))
    .exec(session => {
      val walkInId = session("walkInId").as[String]
      session
    })
    .exec(http("Update Walkin Fields")
      .put(s"/organizations/${organizationId}/locations/${locationId}/walkins/${walkInId}/fields")
      .body(StringBody("""{
        "internalName": "First Name",
        "values": ["Steve"]
      },
      {
        "internalName": "Phone Number",
        "values": ["+11010101010"]
      },
      {
        "internalName": "Email",
        "values": ["abc@abc.com"]
      }""")).asJson)
    .exec(http("Schedule Walkin")
      .put(s"/organizations/${organizationId}/locations/${locationId}/resources/walkins/${walkInId}")
      .body(StringBody("""{ "action": "SCHEDULE", "source": "WEB_KIOSK" }""")).asJson)

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

When I run this script I get the error message as

```
not found: value walkInId
                .put(s"/organizations/${organizationId}/locations/${locationId}/walkins/${walkInId}/fields")
                                                                                          ^
13:42:33.204 [ERROR] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - ./user-files/simulations/Test2.scala:63:89: not found: value walkInId
                .put(s"/organizations/${organizationId}/locations/${locationId}/resources/walkins/${walkInId}")
                                                                                                    ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of problem is that you use String interpolation.
`s"/organizations/${organizationId}/locations/${locationId}/walkins/${walkInId}/fields"`

---

`s` before String means to use variable from your code instead of Gatling's Session variables, and your `${walkInId}` is trying to find this variable in the class. For avoid this you need to escape character, just add additional `$`:
`s"/organizations/${organizationId}/locations/${locationId}/walkins/$${walkInId}/fields"`

---

**UPDATE**: How said the Gatling owner - it's better to update Gatling version in your tests. From **version 3.7** Gatling provides a new format for Expression Language and you can use `#{}` without any problems with interpolation. Here you are page that explains how to upgrade to this version - https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/upgrading/3.6-to-3.7/

Comment: Better: use the new Gatling EL #{} syntax that doesn’t clash with Scala and Kotlin string interpolation.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE Yep, I totally agree with this

Comment: Thank you so much @Amerousful and StéphaneLANDELLE. It worked well with the new Gatling EL #{}.